# why disk space issues corrupts pg_statistic table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Whenever I encounter disk space issues pg_statistic table gets corrupted and Postgres starts to throw the following error

> could not read block 683 in file "base/16384/18200": read only 0 of
>   8192 bytes

it disappears when I do DELETE FROM pg_statistic and then VACUUM

Why Postgres is not able to handle disk space issues?

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question without knowing your system setup. Probably your storage is not reliable, or you set `fsync = off`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am using default postgres.conf, which has fsync = on, what do you mean by storage is not reliable?

Comment: I'm not sure, anything that corrupts your data. PostgreSQL is not in the habit of corrupting tables on crash.